# Controlling what value appears in a column while doing a join

Tags: mysql, join

This one's kind of complicated, so hopefully I can make it clear.

I have two tables:

```
views:
+---------------------+-------------+------------------+
| time                | remote_host | referer          |
+---------------------+-------------+------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 10.0.13.2   | http://foo.com/a |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 10.0.13.1   | http://foo.com/b |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 10.0.13.2   | http://moo.com   |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 10.0.13.2   | http://hi.com    |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 10.0.13.1   | http://foo.com/c |
+---------------------+-------------+------------------+

test_websites:
+----+----------------+------+
| id | url            | name |
+----+----------------+------+
|  1 | http://foo.com |      |
|  2 | http://moo.com |      |
+----+----------------+------+
```

I have a query that very nearly does what I want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, remote_host, url FROM test_websites  
JOIN views ON referer LIKE CONCAT(url, '%') 
GROUP BY test_websites.url 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Results look like this:

```
+-------+-------------+----------------+
| count | remote_host | url            |
+-------+-------------+----------------+
|     3 | 10.0.13.2   | http://foo.com |
|     1 | 10.0.13.2   | http://moo.com |
+-------+-------------+----------------+
```

To explain, I'm trying to get the top 10 viewed websites, however the website URLs are defined in test_websites.  Since `http://foo.com` is an entry in test_websites, all entries that start with `http://foo.com` should be counted as "one website."  Hence the join is based on a `LIKE` condition, and it's correctly counting 3 for http://foo.com in the results.

So, the problem is that I want remote_host to be that entry that appears the most for those rows in views that start with http://foo.com.  In this case, there are two rows starting with http://foo.com in the views table that have 10.0.13.1 as the remote_host, and so the results should show that 10.0.13.1 the remote_host column, and not the remote_host that appears with the first entry that starts with http://foo.com, as it is doing now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Please try the following corrected query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as count, 
    (
        SELECT A.remote_host
        FROM views AS A
        WHERE A.referer LIKE CONCAT(test_websites.url, '%')
        GROUP BY A.remote_host
        ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS max_count_remote_host,
    test_websites.url 
FROM 
    test_websites  
    JOIN views ON views.referer LIKE CONCAT(test_websites.url, '%') 
GROUP BY 
    test_websites.url 
ORDER BY 
    count DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Here you could find a **[working SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b12d01/3)**.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did a little modification - now it should be OK. Regards :) - and thank you. BTW, just to be fair, I think that the approach is based on something I've seen in one of Gordon Linoff's answers.

Comment: Oh whoops, actually I think there's a little error in this query.  After the line `FROM views AS A`, there needs to be `JOIN test_websites`, or else mysql will produce the error `
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'test_websites.url' in 'where clause'`  But thanks a lot!  This one is complicated.

Comment: I'm sorry for the error in the previous version - one level of query nesting too much. I've just corrected the query and added a **[working SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b12d01/3)**. And please note there is no JOIN in the nested query. Regards :)